# Access windows user folder from ubuntu live

Tags: windows-7, users

How can i access windows users directory from ubuntu live to backup some files before format.
It is showing me empty folder but i know that it is not empty?

Folder `/media/somepart/Users/Myuser` is empty but i know it is not.

If i where under windows i could perform take over ownership of that directory but i do not know how to do that under linux.

Can you help me to transfer files ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in the wrong place. On the left bar, there should be something like OSDISK or `XXX GB Filesystem`. You want to pick the one where Windows is installed(try a few). Your documents will be stored in `Documents and Settings/[Your username]/My Documents` or `Users/[Your username]/My Documents`. You can copy them to a flash drive. You can also do this after installing as long as you don't pick the option to remove Windows while installing.

Comment: I know that but i cannot get to /[Your username]/My Documents
im stuck at /[Your username]/ because that folder is empty.

Comment: Try the other parent directory(if you used Users, use Documents and Settings or vice versa. The files must be there or your Windows installation is strangely configured.

Comment: i tryed both but there is no files. If i try to acces files from guest account i cannot acces this specific user.
Can it be because this username is password protected ?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Are you using Windows EFS?

Comment: windows 7 pro. no efs

Answer (score 0):

try with sudo: `sudo cd /media/somepart/Users/Myuser`

I do **not** recommend to use chmod, since this can ruin Windows-Permissions (wrong order for windows), that computer behaves unpredictable (not reproducible) and might won't start any more (at least can't log in with this user). I ruined Win7 this way, with [cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin). (I applied chmod on the whole disk including C:\Windows, I reinstalled Windows)